# Write response of a request into json file several times during execution with python

Tags: python, json, rest, http

I have an application that makes GET requests to an API to get data every given seconds. What I want to do is to write every response I get into a single (ideally json) file to process that data so I can then send a json POST request to a different API. I have the following function that when called by a scheduler only writes the first response and not a single more. How can I achieve a way to write all the responses into a single file for later use.

```
def send_request():
    url = "API URL"

    try:
        # sending get request and saving the response as response object
        r = requests.get(url = url)

    except (requests.Timeout, requests.ConnectionError, requests.HTTPError) as err:
        print("Error while trying to GET data")
        print(err)

    print(r.content)

    data = json.loads(r.content)

    #Json file writer
    with open('data.json', 'w') as outfile:
        json.dump(data, outfile,indent=4, sort_keys=True)
        outfile.flush()
```

The scheduler looks something like this:

```
from apscheduler.schedulers.blocking import BlockingScheduler as scheduler

if __name__ == '__main__':
    sched = scheduler()
    print(time.time())
    sched.add_job(send_request, 'interval', seconds=60)
    sched.start()
```

I am aware that this scheduler may be overkill for the task but it is okay if it isn't the part causing the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you see only the last response in your file as you rewrite it every time.

You should append to your file and not rewrite it:

```
#Json file writer
with open('data.json', 'a') as outfile:
    json.dump(data, outfile, indent=4, sort_keys=True)
    outfile.flush()
```

Note the `a` parameter in `open('data.json', 'a')` which stands for "append"